# multiple tables join on basis of foreign key in single query set in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

i am using sqlite3 database in my python django application: i am defining my table structure which is similar to my actual table schema.

```
table1 having three column:
1. id | primary key | int
2. name | text
3. address | text

table2 having four column:
1. id | primary key | int
2. name_id | foreign key | int 
3. name_info | text
4. address_info | text


table3 having four column:
1. id | primary key | int
2. name_id | foreign key | int 
3. edu_info | text
4. busin_info | text


table4 having four column:
1. id | primary key | int
2. name_id | foreign key | int 
3. progress_info | text
4. inventory_info | text
```

and so on ..

i want to access all table data with in single query in django on the basis of forgein key. its not necessary all tables having same no of record.

i have already set foreign key in all model. like :

```
class table(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(modelname)
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: how to write query in django with above conditions

Answer (score 4):

Use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
YourModel.objects.select_related().filter(foreign_record__foreign_attribute__gt=foo)
```

The select_related gets translated to INNER JOIN query and loads all the data immediately.

Comment: if i want to get data from table2 and table3 on basis of foreign key meanwhile there is no direct relation between table2 and table3. then what will i do?

Comment: What do you mean by "there's no relation between T2 and T2"? That doesn't make sense...

Comment: not T2 and T2. table2 and table3 there is no relation between them.

Comment: I think you should review the database layout. From what I see, there are two possible results. 1) The records in T1 somehow connect the content of T2 and T3, so T1 foreign keys are always unique in T2 and T3. In this case, simply link T2 and T3 together with 1 to 1 relation. 2) If there are more similar foreign keys in T2 or T3, how'd you link the objects together? Which one of the combinations you want? Maybe I'm missing something, but this doesn't sound like a job for your database. It's not a database logic, it's application logic.

Comment: its one to manay relationship . suppose T1 having two record with primary key id 1|2. and table2 and table3 having 12 record (8 record associated with key id 1 adn 4 record associated with key id 2). and same table3. now i want to get all record from both table (table2 and table3) those are available in both table. its very easy if i write simple core query  but how can i do in django can you suggest me?